# sequelize index option runs twice and causes test to fail

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

here is my model:

```
var PaymentsToMonths = db.define('PaymentsToMonths', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    PaymentPlanDetailID: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    month: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL,
        allowNull: false,
        // todo add validation 1-12
    },
    year: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    sum: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    monthTotal: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL,
        allowNull: false,
    }
    
}, {
    tableName: 'PaymentsToMonths',
    freezeTableName: true, // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
    timestamps: true,
    indexes: [
        {
            unique: true,
            fields: ['PaymentPlanDetailID', 'month', 'year'],
            name: 'unique_payment_per_month_and_year'
        }
    ]
})
```

when running tests I see this error:

```
  console.error
    SequelizeDatabaseError: Duplicate key name 'unique_payment_per_month_and_year'
```

which is due to running these 2 identical rows:

```
  console.log
    Executing (default): ALTER TABLE `PaymentsToMonths` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_payment_per_month_and_year` (`PaymentPlanDetailID`, `month`, `year`)

      at Sequelize.log (../node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:1171:15)

  console.log
    Executing (default): ALTER TABLE `PaymentsToMonths` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_payment_per_month_and_year` (`PaymentPlanDetailID`, `month`, `year`)
```

why is this happening?

not sure if related, but I have this code as well for tests:

```
afterAll(async (done) => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();

    // remove all data and tables
    await sequelize.drop();

    // to end the jest process
    done();

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was due to using

```
sequelize.sync({force: false})
```

in my `main_test.js` file.

stupid mistake..

removing one of them worked.